# Arriving from Myanmar by Finnair via Helsinki to Geneva Airport. British passport is it permitted to go directly to France, second residence?

Tags: transit, uk-citizens, covid-19, hel, gva

Work contract  completed after 5 years in Yangon. Want to travel from Myanmar by Finnair via Helsinki to Geneva Airport. British passport is it permitted to go directly to France, second residence? We have no residence in the UK. Our main residence is in central asia and I cannot get a visa as borders closed indefinately.

Comment: Are you asking if you can currently travel to France as a British passport holder?  Do you have any kind of status in France? I'm assuming not from your comment about visas, but your question isn't entirely clear.

Comment: Finnair does not fly directly to Myanmar.  Are you connecting via eg. Bangkok?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.